# MissingInputExceptions in snakemake

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake

I'm trying to make a Snakefile that takes all files in a directory then creates outputs in a seperate folder with the same names.

My code is:

```
strain = glob_wildcards("resources/bin/{isolate}.fasta")

rule all:
    input:
        expand("results/cctyper/{isolate}/", isolate=strain)

rule cctyper:
    input:
        "resources/bin/{isolate}.fasta"
    output:
        directory("results/cctyper/{isolate}/")
    conda:
        "cctyper"
    shell:
        """
        mkdir {output}
        touch {output}/cas_operons.tab
        """
```

(The shell output is a stand in because of platform problems).

But I keep getting errors like this:

```
MissingInputException in rule cctyper in file /Users/cloudy/PRACStest/workflow/Snakefile, line 7:
Missing input files for rule cctyper:
    output: results/cctyper/['SAMEA5061681', 'SAMEA5061682']
    wildcards: isolate=['SAMEA5061681', 'SAMEA5061682']
    affected files:
        resources/bin/['SAMEA5061681', 'SAMEA5061682'].fasta
```

I've tried making the rule use expand() instead of just using the wildcards (since I specify it anyway) but it doesn't seem to fix it. Why doesn't snakemake think the files are there immediately after listing all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glob_wildcards` will return a tuple of lists, so to be sure that you are only storing the necessary list (rather than a tuple), use:

```py
strain, = glob_wildcards("resources/bin/{isolate}.fasta")
```